# pagina multilenguaje

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-blade

Estoy tratando  de realizar una pagina multilenguaje, tengo el problema que la ruta es post, solo he logrado  hacerlo por el metodo get pero como paso contraseñas por ese formulario no puedo mandarlo por get.

les comparto el codigo

Estas son las rutas que utilizo aca lo  cambie por  any para que aqcepte cualquier metodo pero al  hacer eso me manda este error

> La página localhost te ha redirigido demasiadas veces. Borrar las
>   cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { 

Route::any('/welcome', 'Controller@welcome');
```

Route::any('lang/{lang}', function (Request $request, $lang) {

```
    $locale = substr($request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);
    if ($lang) {
        session(['lang' => $lang]);
        return \Redirect::back();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
})->where([
    'lang' => 'en|es'
]);
```

});

este es el middleware

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     if (!empty(session('lang'))) {
        \App::setLocale(session('lang'));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

y los enlaces con los cuales llamo la ruta

```
        <li><a href="lang/fr" class="linkfr" value="fr">French</a></li>


         <li><a href="lang/es" id="linkes"  value="es">Spanish</a></li>
```

Comment: no estas validando nada en route solo entra y redirige y asi en un loop infinito!

Comment: @Bryro gracias por tu respuesta, pero en otra aplicación donde solo utilizo get si funciona perfecto no  me genera un loop realiza el  cambio del idioma  al recargar la pagina. en cambio  en  esta si hace lo  que tu comentas.

Comment: dale un `$locale = substr($request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);` y luego validas si es usuario tiene `es` no haces nada si no mandas `en` y hay si el `redirect` o biseversa no se como lo deses!

Comment: Disculpa esta pregunta valido si lang trae es o en cierto?

Comment: exacto porque de momento tu le estas mandando a configurar lo que se le pase solamente y cuando regresa vuelve a entrar configura y asi eternamente! esto te puede servir [laravel language](https://glutendesign.com/posts/detect-and-change-language-on-the-fly-with-laravel)

Comment: @Bryro he editado el codigo de la pregunta me podrias decir  si  esa es la forma  en que me indicabas, si  es  asi me sigue generando el bucle.